# Spring-WS: consume service

Tags: java, maven, soap, pom.xml, spring-ws

I try to follow the example on spring site to consume a SOAP web service (https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) :

The application works, it consume correctly the services, but on the pom.xml file there is an error.
The part of pom that give the error is :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>home.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The error is on the goal tag :

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate failed. (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL(ModelLoader.java:390)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:158)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:117)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.loadModel(XJC23Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute(XJC23Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute(XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 31 more
    pom.xml        /FrankSOAPClient        line 45        Maven Build Problem
```

Comment: Are you sure you did this step: *Run the target web service locally* by verifying that WSDL is there? It seems like maven cannot access your local server with WSDL.

Comment: Actually i developed the webservice with springboot and it run locally.